# C++ Inheritance Issue

Tags: c++, subclass

I am using code::blocks, with, I believe gcc. Given the example code (this is pseudo code and may not replicate the problem):

```
//Assume this is in a separate header file to B
class TestA
{
    protected:
        int A;

    public:
        void Function1(){A = 0;}
};

class TestB : public TestA
{
    public:
        void CallFunction(){ A = 10; Function1();}//
};
```

I would get similar compile errors, like:
Error: 'A' not declared in this scope.
Error: Function1() not declared in this scope.

I was under the impression that all base variables and functions were inherited to the subclass. Given the base class has a lot of functions and variables, I don't want to use the 'using' keyword as I'd have to declare it for every function and variable (to my knowledge).

Is there any way to make it so TestB explicitly or actually includes the stuff it's inheriting?

**Relevant snippets below**

Okay. It's not possible to include example code as it's in project, but I will quote the key snippets:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\Projects\RND2\TemplateListAdv.h|30|error: 'Size' was not declared in this scope|
```

The line this is on is:

```
if(!Array.SetToSize(Size))
```

The class it's in is:

```
template<typename TemplateItem>
class TemplateListAdv : public TemplateList<TemplateItem>
```

And the incriminating line from TemplateList is:

```
SIZE_TYPE Size; //SIZE_TYPE is unsigned long.
//SIZE_TYPE is available in all files as unsigned long.
```

Files go:
TemplateList.h->TemplateBasics.h->TemplateListAdv.h

No missing files from what I can see.

I will tack in, the 'using' keyword resolves it individually, but this has been bugging me as I thought inheritance was automatic.

Compiler data as requested:

"Release 10.05  rev 6283 (2010-05-27 09:09:13)   gcc 4.4.1 Windows/unicode - 32 bit"

Comment: This should work as expected, so you'll have to find an example which acually fails...

Comment: try posting the real code and the files they are in. as far as i can tell it just looks like you don't have #include "testa.h" in testb.cpp

Comment: Post the code which gives an error, this code has no errors.

Comment: Can you confirm which compiler you're using exactly? If you go "Project->build options" you should see "GNU GCC Compiler" in a drop-down list inside the dialog which opens. If it is GCC, go to command line and type `gcc --version` to see which version of GCC your running. I have tried it under GCC 4.6.1 and it works correctly (no errors).

Comment: @Ken Hi. I can confirm it's gcc. I can't find the command line you refer to but if you can point me to it I'll type in the command.

Comment: To have a slight chance that someone will eventually provide a helpful answer you need to provide code that *actually* demonstrates the problem you're asking about. Spend some time reducing your code to a manageable example that still contains the problem. It's actually likely that by doing so you'll find a solution yourself.

Comment: I don't see any relevance in the scenario you quoted first, and the code snippets you have posted later. And even that is little helpful to provide you a conclusive answer.

Comment: I did not know what I was looking for. To me I wouldn't have thought templates would have made a difference. I have a problem, not the answer - I cannot provide what I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you're having about accessing base class stuff in a class *template*, is a [FAQ item](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19).

Rather then quoting the whole FAQ item here, I just link to it: that's your answer.

The code that you presented to illustrate the problem was unrelated, sorry. It is always a good idea to give an actual example rather than an example of what one thinks might be the problem.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: @SSight3: You can convert the *non-dependent* expression `Size` into a *dependent* one by prefixing it with `this`: `this->Size` will tell the compiler that the expression is *dependent* on the template arguments, and then (*magic happens*: lookup is postponed to instantiation, where the base is also instantiated and) it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like you are getting error wite template classes inheritance, isn't it? They are a big difference comparing to non-template ones. Assuming you have code like this:

```
template <class T>
class TestA
{
    protected:
        int A;

    public:
        void Function1(){A = 0;}
};

template <class T>
class TestB : public TestA<T>
{
    public:
        void CallFunction(){ A = 10; Function1();}//
};
```

The issue is caused by *two-phase name lookup*. All members of the base TestA class are *dependent names*, i.e. they depend on the template argument T. This is so because you can have template specialization for TestA with totally different members, e.g.:

```
template <class T>
class TestA
{
    protected:
        int A;

    public:
        void Function1(){A = 0;}
};

template <class T>
class TestB : public TestA<T>
{
    public:
        void CallFunction(){ A = 10; Function1();}//
};

template <>
class TestA<int>
{
};
```

Now, there is no A and Function1 members in the TestA, so they would be unaccessible in TestB as well. In order to let compiler know that these members are indeed depende on the template argument you should write TestB like this:

```
template <class T>
class TestB : public TestA<T>
{
    public:
        void CallFunction(){ this->A = 10; this->Function1();}//
};
```

This way you make compiler resolve names only during template instantiation time instead of template declaration time and it will known about base class members.

One thing to add is that there is no such issue with VC compiler, it doesn't try to parse templates until instantiation and thus don't support two-phase name lookup.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using templates, and the base class is a 'dependent name'. That is, the template base class could be specialized and not have the Size member, the compiler just doesn't know when it compiles your class, because the `Size` reference is not in a dependent context.

In your particular case the easiest solution is to refer to the inherited members using `this`:

```
if(!Array.SetToSize(this->Size))
```

And since `this` is a dependent name, it should work

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that :

- Size is a protected or public attribute of TemplateList ?
- you're not calling if(!Array.SetToSize(Size)) from a static method ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is really bad, and you might want to improve on that. Anyway, my crystal ball tells me that `Size` is defined in a base template, and that because the identifier `Size` is not *dependent* lookup is not going into the base template and the compiler not seeing it. Add a `this->` before `Size` and you should be set.

Comment: Suggestions for improvements?

Comment: If suggestions are on how to improve the question: templates are very specific beasts in the language, any question where the problem originally contains templates should start there, in some cases it won't be relevant, but in others it will be. Do not provide code examples that do not replicate the problem, try to replicate the same error in your environment in a smaller test case, it will either help you understand the problem and what parts of it are relevant (in this case, it would have shown you that removing the template eliminated the problem: template matters)

Answer (score 1):

When interpreting a template member function, the compiler must (following the standard) decide for each symbol if it is dependent on the template parameter. If it is dependent on it, then it'll only be resolved when the template is instantiated. However, he must resolve it at this moment.

In your case, the compiler think that `A` and `Function1` don't depend on the template parameter and should thus be resolvable just after the parse. You just have to make it depend on the template parameter by using `this->A` and `this->Function1`

So, you should have something like that.

```
template < typename T >
class Base
{
protected:
  int A;

public:
  void Function1() { A = 0; }
};

template < typename T >
class Derived : public Base< T >
{
public:
  void CallFunction1() {
    this->A = 10;
    this->Function1();
  }
};
```